# How to make Left Ctrl (while pressed) as key to choose 3rd level (Alt Gr key)

Tags: keyboard-layout

Is there a way to make Left Ctrl (while pressed) as key to choose 3rd level (Alt Gr key)? In Ubuntu/Gnome/Cinnamon, there isn't an option for it in the Keyboard Layouts Options:
[Cinnamon-keyboard-layout-options](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Ry49hmVI-rQ/V4OFjFVI8nI/AAAAAAAACtQ/2rvUwb4zmbQcULhUccMraVGlIZvW2yXUwCLcB/s1600/05%2BCinnamon%2Bkeyboard.png)

Swapping Left Control and Window key, and then making the "new" Window key (while pressed) as a 3rd level key doesn't seem to work.

Edit: I edited the question to change Compose key to key to choose 3rd level (Alt Gr key) and add "while pressed" to it. Compose key and 3rd level key are different.

[For example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key):

```
C → c (lower case — first level)
⇧ Shift+C → C (upper case — second level)
AltGr+C → © (copyright sign — third level)
AltGr+⇧ Shift+C → ¢ (cent sign — fourth level)
```

Comment: What is meant by 'third level key'?

Comment: I have modified my question, please check.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be a way, at least not an easy one. These are the prepared options:

```
$ cat /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst | grep lv3
  lv3                  Key to choose 3rd level
  lv3:switch           Right Ctrl
  lv3:menu_switch      Menu
  lv3:win_switch       Any Win key
  lv3:lwin_switch      Left Win
  lv3:rwin_switch      Right Win
  lv3:alt_switch       Any Alt key
  lv3:lalt_switch      Left Alt
  lv3:ralt_switch      Right Alt
  lv3:ralt_switch_multikey Right Alt, Shift+Right Alt key is Compose
  lv3:ralt_alt         Right Alt key never chooses 3rd level
  lv3:enter_switch     Enter on keypad
  lv3:caps_switch      Caps Lock
  lv3:bksl_switch      Backslash
  lv3:lsgt_switch      &lt;Less/Greater&gt;
  lv3:caps_switch_latch Caps Lock chooses 3rd level, acts as onetime lock when pressed together with another 3rd-level-chooser
  lv3:bksl_switch_latch Backslash chooses 3rd level, acts as onetime lock when pressed together with another 3rd-level-chooser
  lv3:lsgt_switch_latch &lt;Less/Greater&gt; chooses 3rd level, acts as onetime lock when pressed together with another 3rd-level-chooser
```

So <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> (and quite a few other) can be turned to a 3rd level key, but not <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. That's unfortunate. I prefer left Ctrl to all others. I think I'll settle using left alt and redefine all shortcuts with alt to use win key instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to dash, then search **Keyboard**.
2. Select **Shortcuts** tab, navigate to **Typing** on left side panel.
3. Click **Compose Key**, change the value from Disabled to Left Ctrl.

[image]

4. Close Keyboard configuration, test your compose key then.

Open your favorite text editor, for example I'll use GEdit. Hit and release the Left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, followed by word **T** and **M**. If the output show Trademark symbol (™), it means you have successfully enabled Compose Key.

Comment: Thank you for your very quick response! I have checked that I could do it for Compose key but I couldn't for 3rd level key. I have edited the question, please check.

Comment: What do you mean by "3rd level key" ?

Comment: I meant making Left Ctrl an Alt Gr key [German_keyboard_layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout)